# How to show Transcribe language links only if it has entries?

Tags: transcribe

The [Transcribe documentation](http://eeharbor.com/transcribe/documentation) about the language_link tag:

> Using the entry_id parameter in conjunction with the has_entry
>   parameter will only output links for languages that have entries
>   related to the entry_id passed in

I can't get it to work, and no example to be found. The documentation mixes variables and tag parameters, it's not clear.

**Anybody here that knows how to only show a language link when the current viewed entry has an entry for that language?**

Comment: Post your code.

Comment: I got the answer froom EE Harbor support. Will paste it here!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tom from EE Harbor helped me out, here's his answer:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="name" ....}

    {exp:transcribe:language_links has_entry="yes" entry_id="{entry_id}" parse="inward"}
            <select name="lang">
                {languages}
                    <option value="{abbreviation}"{if current} selected="selected"{/if}>{name}</option>
                {/languages}
            </select>
    {/exp:transcribe:language_links}

{/exp:channel:entries}
```

> Please note, you will need to place the language_links tags inside the channel:entries tags.

This fixed it for me, I didn't place the code inside the channel:entries tag.